# Windows Phone Caliburn Micro HyperLink click event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro for a Windows Phone app. I have a hyperlink control for which I want to bind the click event to my View Model. Below is the sample code

XAML, MyPage.xaml

```
<TextBlock>  
<Run>Got to</Run>
<Hyperlink micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action OpenAnotherPage]">
My Page</Hyperlink><Run Text="."></Run></TextBlock>
```

ViewModel MyPageViewModel.cs

```
public void OpenAnotherPage()
{
// some code
}
```

When I tap on the link, I get an exception

> System.Exception: No target found for method

What could be the problem?

Update 1: Tried setting `micro:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=DataContext}"` on the Hyperlink control, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Give the TextBlock a name and use that as the ElementName since you have the Hyperlink nested into that control.  Then Update1 should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following XAML (untested):

```
    <Hyperlink>My Page
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ec:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OpenAnotherPage" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Hyperlink>
```

The namespaces are following (you'll need to reference those 2 assemblies, they're by Microsoft and shipped with MS Expression Blend)

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```